# Procedure conversion in Oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle11g

I am a new member here so apologies from me if i am not able to follow the rules here.
I am using Oracle 11g express edition along with pl/sql. I am trying to convert a database of sql server in oracle 11g. So far i have done everything.
But now i am trying to convert `procedures`. I have done all changing but still i am not able to make procedures completely.

This is code of procedure in SQL server:

```
create proc Result_proc 
@name varchar(40),
@Test varchar(40)
as
(
select * from [Result View] where ([Student Name] = @name AND Test# IN (@Test)) 
)
```

Converted code in ORACLE:

```
create or replace procedure Result_proc ( 
p_name varchar2,
p_Test varchar2)
as
begin
(
select * from ahmad where (Student_Name = p_name AND Test# IN (p_Test)) 
)
end;
```

Here in the image you see when i run the converted code in PL/SQL it is not executed properly:[Output of CONVERTED proc in PL/SQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smfuB.png)

Output:

```
SQL> 10
```

Comment: ["SQL" is a language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL). Do you mean SQL Server, perhaps? Please post the output as text, [not an image](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Although it looks like you're just missing a slash `/` on its on to end the procedure definition?

Comment: A good tip when learning a new language is to read the official documentation. You can find [the PL/SQL user's guide here](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/title.htm). Your code has a couple of trivial syntax errors which you should be able to spot for yourself by comparing it with the examples in the manual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL Server this stored procedure means 'return result of this select statement to the client'. It's common way in MSSQL to return recordsets.

When using Oracle, default way of do this is to use ref cursor output parameter. This procedure should be converted in something similar to

```
create procedure Result_Proc(p_Name varchar2, p_Test varchar2, p_Result out sys_refcursor) is
begin
  open p_result for
    select * from "Result View" where student_name = p_Name and test# = p_Test;
end;
```

But generally better way is to drop such junk procedures at all. Unlike MSSQL, Oracle does not require such select SPs as security call. More powerful and handy method is to just select what you need directly.